# How to install converted .exe in silent mode

Tags: windows-installer, exe

I have a .msi file that I want to install silently. However, it appears that it has a dependency module that keeps asking for user input. So the first part of the package gets installed, but by the time it reached the dependency module it is asking for user input. The command that I used was msiexec /i setup.msi /quiet.

I also want to change the destination folder for the installation from the default during installaiton. I am not able to do this with msiexec. I read where transforms could be used but I do not know which the name of the property to edit.

So I decided to convert the .msi file to a .exe since I know I can create an answer file for .exe. However, the resulting .exe file does not recognise the silent switch nor does it create and answer file when the /r switch is supplied. I used Ultimate MSI to EXE Converter Trial for the conversion. So my questions are:

1. How do I get the .exe that I converted from .msi to recognise the silent switch?
2. How do I surpress the dependency module in the .msi file?
3. How do I create a response file for .msi files?

I would rather not go back t the software vendor on this if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a transform is the correct thing to do.  The exact table data to modify depends on the MSI in question.    Some MSI's would require modifying the Directory table and set would require modifying the CustomAction table. ( Type 51 or Type 35 CA's that override the default values in the Directory table ).

As for the dependency check, that could be the LaunchConditions table or a type 19 CA scheduled in the InstallUISequence and/or InstallExecuteSequence table.

I could give a better answer if I could see the MSI.  Once you have a proper transform the commandline would be:

```
msiexec /I foo.msi /qn TRANSFORMS=foo.mst
```